# How to fix "singular fit" with glmer (lme4) in R?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

## Problem

I am trying to fit glmer models with variables varying between 0 and 1 using lme4 in R but I always get the "singular fit" error. I have tried different things but is has been impossible to get rid of this error so far. (I have exactly the same error for another model in which variables vary between -1 and 1)

## Backgrounds and things I tried

I want to predict how movement between birds on day X (mvt_index) predict the association index on day X+1 (sbs_nextday). I have 6 flocks (aviaries) of 28 birds from 3 lines (high,low, wild type) on a period of 28 days. Here 5 randomly sampled lines of my data set (fulldata_mod1.2):

```
             date pair_id aviaries lines sbs_nextday mvt_index
57552  2017-06-15   70_83       G3     W 0.007614837 0.0000000
118075 2017-06-24 158_159       G6     H 0.001187648 0.0000000
13727  2017-06-28 125_143       G2     L 0.001333333 0.0000000
106103 2017-06-18   65_82       G3     W 0.002484913 0.1666667
24790  2017-07-06   41_52       G5     L 0.004279601 0.2500000
```

Association index (sbs_nextday) and movement index (mvt_index) vary between 0 and 1. In the following model (mod1.2) each data point represent a value of association index and movement index per dyad (pair_id) and per day (date). The first model I ran was this one:

```
mod1.2 <- lmer(sbs_nextday ~ mvt_index  + (1|pair_id) + (1|date) + (1|aviaries) + (1|lines),data=fulldata_mod1.2, lmerControl(optCtrl = list(maxfun = 10000)))


Error in if (REML) p else 0L : argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (REML) p else 0L :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

After re thinking a bit my model I decided to remove date as random effect because as I have one value per dyad and per day, pair_id and date will explain the same variance if both are used as random effects. Then, each aviary has its set of individual ids (and pair_id). Hence, I used pair_id as a nested random effect within aviaries. Finally, as I have truncated data (between 0 and 1) I can't use a lmer because it will try to fit a gaussian distribution and it's not possible with my data. On top of that I have a zero-inflated data set, so I used a glmer model with binomial family and logit link function as follow:

```
mod1.2 <- glmer(cbind(sbs_nextday, (1-sbs_nextday)) ~ mvt_index  + (1|aviaries/pair_id), data=fulldata_mod1.2, family=binomial(link='logit'))

boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize, rho) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!

summary(mod1.2)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(sbs_nextday, (1 - sbs_nextday)) ~ mvt_index + (1 | aviaries/pair_id)
   Data: fulldata_mod1.2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   392.5    426.7   -192.2    384.5    39069 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.0406 -0.0076  0.0700  0.4228 30.1497 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 pair_id:aviaries (Intercept) 0        0       
 aviaries         (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 39073, groups:  pair_id:aviaries, 2254; aviaries, 6

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -7.6670     0.2554 -30.024   <2e-16 ***
mvt_index     1.2567     0.5989   2.098   0.0359 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
          (Intr)
mvt_index -0.577
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I looked at ?isSingular, and checked the variance-covariance matrix:

```
VarCorr(mod1.2)
 Groups           Name        Std.Dev.
 pair_id:aviaries (Intercept) 0       
 aviaries         (Intercept) 0
```

Then I checked if my dataset was balanced for each variable in the model:

```
lines:
table(fulldata_mod1.2$lines)
    H     L     W 
12171 13988 12914

aviaries:
table( fulldata_mod1.2$aviaries)
  G1   G2   G3   G4   G5   G6 
5176 6822 7193 5721 7166 6995

date:
table( fulldata_mod1.2$date)
2017-06-12 2017-06-13 2017-06-14 2017-06-15 2017-06-16 2017-06-17 2017-06-18 2017-06-19 2017-06-20 2017-06-21 
      1113       1914       1995       1839       1861       1788       1652       1703       1574       1398 
2017-06-22 2017-06-23 2017-06-24 2017-06-25 2017-06-26 2017-06-27 2017-06-28 2017-06-29 2017-06-30 2017-07-01 
      1854       1497       1578       1457       1204       1494       1179       1128        826       1220 
2017-07-02 2017-07-03 2017-07-04 2017-07-05 2017-07-06 2017-07-07 2017-07-08 2017-07-09 
       486       1300       1049       1087       1471       1054       1256       1096
```

I used then a glm to check if the model worked without random effects:

```
mod1.4 <- glm(cbind(sbs_nextday, (1-sbs_nextday)) ~ mvt_index   ,data=fulldata_mod1.2,family=binomial(link='logit'))
Warning message:
In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!

summary(mod1.4)

Call:
glm(formula = cbind(sbs_nextday, (1 - sbs_nextday)) ~ mvt_index, 
    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = fulldata_mod1.2)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-0.25747  -0.17050  -0.13572  -0.04642   2.17994  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.22387    0.04689 -90.083  < 2e-16 ***
mvt_index    0.83360    0.12672   6.578 4.76e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2011.4  on 39072  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1973.3  on 39071  degrees of freedom
AIC: 1488.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
```

So when I compare both glm and glmer's summary I have approximatively the same results. But I want to control for the random effects and the model still not working. I will really appreciate if you can give me some advices, and I thank you already for the time you will use for that.

Comment: Your response variable (sbs_nextday) seems continuous between 0 and 1. So you either have to use lmer(), or if sbs_nextday is actually some kind of proportion, you need to include the total number sampled in each trial, e.g. by specifying a weights argument. The result of the call to glmer() also shows that the estimated variances of the random effects are 0. This will cause a warning on a singular fit. Indeed, then you might as well run a glm without random effects.